# Storing lines in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I have to make this program where I have to get the lines from a text file and then print out only the last ten lines of the file. If the lines are less than 10 in the text file then print out the entire file. So far I have this code. I am stuck on how to store the lines in a vector or array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    string filename;
    vector <string> filelines(100);
    string line;
    cout << "Enter the name of the file you wish to open. ";
    cin >> filename;

    //open the file.
    file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (file)
    {
        cout << "File opened successfully." << endl;
        int index = 0;
        while (getline(file,line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}

my sample text file looks like this
This is line 0
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6
This is line 7
This is line 8
This is line 9
This is line 10
This is line 11
This is line 12
This is line 13
This is line 14
This is line 15
This is line 16
This is line 17
This is line 18
This is line 19
This is line 20
This is line 21
This is line 22
This is line 23
This is line 24
This is line 25
This is line 26
This is line 27
This is line 28
This is line 29
This is line 30
This is line 31
This is line 32
This is line 33
This is line 34
```

Comment: Don't pre-size your vector to an arbitrary number of strings. Create it empty and use `while (getline(file,line)) { filelines.push_back(line); }`. Alternatively, scan through the whole file counting the number of lines and remember the position of the last 10 lines. This will save memory when reading a huge file.

Comment: When i type the line you gave me it tells me "filelines must have a class type." I removed the 100 in the vector declaration statement.
error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union

while (getline(file,line))
  {
   cout << line << endl;
   filelines.push_back(line);
  }

Comment: Use `vector <string> filelines;` as `vector <string> filelines();` defines a function which takes no parameters and returns a vector of strings. Welcome to C++

Comment: ok it worked. I had a small syntax error in the declaration of the vector. thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am stuck on how to store the lines in a vector or array because i need something that is similar to the arraylist in Java whereby i don't know exactly how many lines will be there in the text file.

Since you're using `std::vector` you don't need to know how many lines are in the file in order to insert them. The vector will accommodate the elements you want to insert by growing its internal array. Insert the lines into the vector using `push_back()`, and then you have the lines themselves along with the amount.